# how to send multiple information in Java API

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, spring-data-jpa

I am building a java API, it will pull the data from a database and write to a CSV file,
so I have written the code like below:

```
InputStreamResource filecontent = //generate csv file
return ResponseEntity.ok().header(Httpheaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"attachment; filename="+ createdfilename).contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/csv").body(filecontent);
```

Now since the database record is growing up huge,
I have converted the retrieve of data into pageable.

Now I want to send both filecontent and pageable data response in the API response as below:

```
    Response --> clickable download link and  
                 {
                   totalitems:"",
                   current page:"",
                   noofpage:""
                 }
```

Can someone guide on this how to do in Java API?

Comment: You could try using `multipart/form-data` for the response or use HTTP headers. Alternatively, you could use a JSON array instead of CSV data

Comment: @dan1stiscrying Does the client is able to parse multipart data?

Comment: Depends on the client.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach can be used in order to easily passing paging and sorting parameters :

```
@GetMapping
ResponseEntity<Page<PostDto>> getPostList(Pageable pageable) {
    final Page<PostDto> response = postService.getPostList(pageable);
    // code omitted
}
```

The preceding method signature causes Spring MVC to try to derive a Pageable instance from the request parameters by using the following default configuration:

•   page - Page you want to retrieve. 0-indexed and defaults to 0.
•   size - Size of the page you want to retrieve. Defaults to 20.
•   sort - Properties that should be sorted by in the format 
•   property,property(,ASC|DESC)(,IgnoreCase). The default sort direction is case-sensitive ascending.

Use multiple sort parameters if you want to switch direction or case sensitivity — for example, ?sort=firstname&sort=lastname,asc&sort=city,ignorecase.

For reference: Spring Docs - [HandlerMethodArgumentResolvers for Pageable and Sort](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.basic.paging-and-sorting)

Here is the example API calls:
{{baseUrl}}/api/v1/comments?page=0&size=10&sort=comment,desc

or;

```
@GetMapping
ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<Page<PostInfo>>> getPosts(
        @RequestParam(name = "page", defaultValue = DEFAULT_PAGE) 
final Integer page,
        @RequestParam(name = "size", defaultValue = DEFAULT_SIZE) final Integer size) {
    // Pageable pageable = Pageable.ofSize(size).withPage(page);
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);
    final Page<PostInfo> response = postService.getPosts(pageable);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse<>(Instant.now(clock).toEpochMilli(), SUCCESS, response));
}
```